# Setting up an Admin Route in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, xml, router

Looking at the core Magento 2 code, there seems to be **two** ways of setting up an admin route.

The first

```
#File: vendor/magento/module-media-storage/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="adminhtml">
            <module name="Magento_MediaStorage" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

is similar to Magento 1.  You add your module to a list of modules in the `adminhtml` route, and Magento checks it for you.

The second

```
#File: vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="cms" frontName="cms">
            <module name="Magento_Cms" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

has you setting up a **new** route (id `cms` above), and then adding your module to it.

Is one of these the "right/preferred" way of doing this in Magento 2?  If not, what are the difference between the two?  i.e. when would you use one over the other?

Asking not to solve a specific problem, but to make sure I'm creating my routes in the correct way and that problems similar to Magento 1 modules (pulling in ajax libraries, security, etc.) are avoided.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The difference is in urls. Url has following structure:
`<areaFrontName>/<moduleFrontName>/<actionPath>/<actionName>`

Route "Adminhtml" has moduleFrontName "admin", same as areaFrontName. So all paths under "adminhtml" route will start with `admin/admin`.

If you want to have a more specific url, you should use specific route, like catalog does it. Catalog urls all start with `admin/catalog`. This is the preferred way.

So preferred configuration is:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="cms" frontName="cms">
            <module name="Magento_Cms"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Note that `before="Magento_Backend"` is not needed

Comment: are there any explanations on naming ID and frontName? should it be the same for admin area? should it use module name? why it is not working when id != frontName ?

Answer (score 5):

I came across this as well while looking for examples how to add an adminhtml controller. I did some research and this is what I've found.

The `route id="adminhtml"` way is used 24 times in the core.

The `before="Magento_Backend"` way is used 31 times in the core.

There are only 50 modules with an adminhtml/routes.xml but 24+31 = 55. Hint #1.

I tried to find a common denominator between what type of modules uses which type, but I can't seem to identify any. So maybe the change was introduced at a certain point in time so I checked the timing on the two types. Unfortunately this was quite hard since most of them were last edited mid-september to introduce the new urn's so I had to use Github's history function.

I then noticed some routes.xml files where the `route id="adminhtml"` option is used **also** use the `before="Magento_Backend"`, see for example [Magento_UrlRewrite's routes.xml file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blame/develop/app/code/Magento/UrlRewrite/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml). I can't seem to find any conclusive commonalities between the three variants.

I also checked the new modules (which weren't in M1 and therefore could not be ported but were written new for M2), such as [AdvancedPricingImportExport](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blame/develop/app/code/Magento/AdvancedPricingImportExport/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml), [Integration](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blame/develop/app/code/Magento/Integration/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml), [MediaStorage](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blame/develop/app/code/Magento/MediaStorage/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml) and [EncryptionKey](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blame/develop/app/code/Magento/EncryptionKey/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml) and although some use the `before="Magento_Backend"` and some don't, they all use the `<route id="adminhtml">` tag. Amongst these, the ones without the `before="Magento_Backend"` were last changed in February 2015 while the ones with that tag all were edited *after* that date.

So, my preliminary conclusion is that this is the preferred way to do it (either explicitly decided on internally at Magento HQ or not);

```
<config xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="adminhtml">
            <module name="Your_Extension" before="Magento_Backend"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

I'd love to hear Magento core dev's position on this, obviously.

UPDATE: Anton Kril responded, see his answer for the preferred way to do this.